# Android Virtual Device install Google APIs Intel Atom

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, google-api, android-virtual-device

I'm using android virtual device for android development.
Each time I want to create an AVD with target Google APIs(Google Inc.) - API level 21, the AVD manager show the message

```
This AVD may not work unless you install the Google APIs Intel Atom (x86) system image for Android 5.0 (API 21) first.
```

Before this, I use Android 5.0 - API level 21 target instead.
What can I do to use the Google APIs target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image` in your Android SDK first, but `Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image` for 64 bit system image you created. Remember, you will always need to install `Google APIs System Image` for every Android SDK API levels. But it excepted for Android 4.4W (API level 20).

**What are the minimum requirements I need to create a phone AVD?**

Open your SDK and install the following:

1. `SDK Platform`
2. `Google APIs` (if found on your SDK).
3. `ARM EABI v7a System Image` or `Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image` (choose one based on your System Image that you will use on your AVD's CPU/ABI).
4. `Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image` (if found on your SDK & if you will use ARM EABI v7a System Image as your AVD's CPU/ABI).
5. `Google APIs (x86 System Image)`or `Google APIs (ARM System Image)` (choose one).
6. `Intel x86 Atom System Image` (don't install if you will use ARM EABI v7a System Image).
7. Create your AVD.

**Note:**

1. Choose one of them based on your System Image that you will use. ARM EABI v7a or Intel Atom x86 only.
2. If you are using `Intel Atom x86 System Image`, you need to install "Intel HAXM" first (search on Google). This system image supports only if your computer's processor is strong and speed enough. My PC is using Intel Core 2 Duo @2.93 GHz E7500, but it's not supported to use Intel HAXM (that means, I can't use `Intel Atom x86 System Image` as my AVD's CPU/ABI. So I need to upgrade my PC's CPU).

Comment: Do you need both `Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image` and `Intel x86 Atom System Image`? Also, should you have both the 64-bit and 32-bit Atom System Images?